# Vim use return value of executed bash command

Tags: bash, vim, return, execute

I am trying to check if a line of code is in a file in vimscript.
I need to use the return value of grep inside my if but I don't know hot get it.

This does not work of course:

```
if $(execute '!grep -q ' . shellescape(lineToAdd) . ' ' . shellescape(g:projectPath))
    echom "Already added."
    return
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `v:shell_error` as seen in this [Vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#v:shell_error),

> Result of the last shell command.  When non-zero, the last
>           shell command had an error.  When zero, there was no problem.
>           This only works when the shell returns the error code to Vim.
>           The value -1 is often used when the command could not be
>           executed.  Read-only.